# Passing a reference of a base class to another function

Tags: c++

Here is the problem i am facing, does anyone have solution?

```
Class A: public class B
{
 // I want to pass a reference of B to Function
}

void ClassC::Function(class& B)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Poorly worded, but reading between the lines, try calling Function() with *this as the parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you are declaring the class is wrong:

```
class A : public B // no more class keyword here
{

}; // note the semicolon

void ClassC::Function(const B &b) // this is how you declare a parameter of type B&
{
}
```

You simply need to pass the object of type `A` to the `Function`. It'll work.
It's good to declare the parameter as `const` if you want to take derived types too.
To pass the `this` instance, you'd simply call:

```
classCObject.Function(*this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just having trouble with the syntax?   It should be

```
void ClassC::Function(B& b)
{
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

to make `b` a reference of type `B`.

Comment: I can do that fine, the issue is passing the pointer to this function